# Document Element showing undefined when using Parse of XML

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing, saml, domparser

My SAML response is contained in the variable **text**.

My parser code:

```
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");
```

My end goal is to pull out the value for RETURN_THIS_VALUE from my SAML response. Below I have the result for the variable oDom.

**oDom**

```js
Dom {
  rawHTML:
'<samlp:Response ID="_146e55d5-5f43-443a-a1b5-5ef2f09ad06d" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-12-06T14:16:27.985Z" Destination="httpcom" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_6b17407f6451fc54076e" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">htttrust</Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /></samlp:Status><Assertion ID="_e90c2462-47e1-4e13-ac87-10e7d0aca2ff" IssueInstant="2018-12-06T14:16:27.985Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><Issuer>http://setrust</Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_e90c2462-47e1-4e13-ac87-10e7d0aca2ff"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>QRT3c4m1p4458PF7rYlbkBX+tqwyscg2nelBkpBWqn4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>dZkCndDEU5TSuFMcioRqgNkjqt1rv3nzmupbYu3RZxNd2hIR5116Mm9y/C8TnK7F6KC6BVBLLJ1BfonMuumFTcCu9hke2U29a/XqhOpRFM2EGde6wWaPgDV2zjfQLSLjO1Tkj7jTe35vIeg5WZhdi91qHOvDSPcH3WcvbslNMHycLnPMANq0MsSO503VW7EsJNPRB8uEkBxAoCOPKG4URojk5+IBeKHHrKREKEJXDss+kiLNgi2flsjVjPpXk8fsMBOgJnSJ1Qjqpu/cAUw8fyn2byxMh7x4wxsBu+pbHm8lNprbmmxRwT4wtiSuQnEDtadeH7ocVJWPWKlEFsaR/w==</ds:SignatureValue><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></KeyInfo></ds:Signature><Subject><NameID>NH37782</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_6b17407f6451fc54076e" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-06T14:21:27.985Z" Recipient="httrtz.com" /></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-06T14:16:27.983Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-06T15:16:27.983Z"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>.com</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group"><AttributeValue>RETURN_THIS_VALUE</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-06T14:16:27.881Z" SessionIndex="_e90c2462-47e1-4e13-ac87-10e7d0aca2ff"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion></samlp:Response>' }
```

I try to convert the oDom variable to a document by doing the following:

```
var doc = oDOM.documentElement;
```

But then if I do a console.log on the variable **doc** I get back undefined. Any ideas why?

Sample of what the text variable looks like on a console.log

```html
<samlp:Response ID="ffff"
                Version="2.0"
                IssueInstant="207Z"
                Destination="htm"
                Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
                xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">sites/trust</Issuer>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /></samlp:Status>
  <Assertion ID="_949bf"
             IssueInstant="201997Z"
             Version="2.0"
             xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <Issuer>sites/trust</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http:/sig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://ww14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www256" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#f">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/" />
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/#" /></ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org" />
          <ds:DigestValue>dig=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>
sig/
</ds:SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>
cert+YCo+==
</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <Subject>
      <NameID>id</NameID>
      <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-05T13:11:26.997Z" />
      </SubjectConfirmation>
    </Subject>
    <Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-05T13:06:26.994Z"
                NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-05T14:06:26.994Z">
    </Conditions>
    <AttributeStatement>
      <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group">
        <AttributeValue>GET_THIS_VALUE</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
    </AttributeStatement>
    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-05T13:05:21.872Z"
                    SessionIndex="_918c9d27-b2f3-4cf3-b5ad-9a0f049249bf">
      <AuthnContext>
        <AuthnContextClassRef>protectt</AuthnContextClassRef>
      </AuthnContext>
    </AuthnStatement>
  </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

```js
var text = '<samlp:Response ID="_146e55d5-5f43-443a-a1b5-5ef2f09ad06d" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-12-06T14:16:27.985Z" Destination="httpcom" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_6b17407f6451fc54076e" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">htttrust</Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /></samlp:Status><Assertion ID="_e90c2462-47e1-4e13-ac87-10e7d0aca2ff" IssueInstant="2018-12-06T14:16:27.985Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><Issuer>http://setrust</Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_e90c2462-47e1-4e13-ac87-10e7d0aca2ff"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>QRT3c4m1p4458PF7rYlbkBX+tqwyscg2nelBkpBWqn4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>dZkCndDEU5TSuFMcioRqgNkjqt1rv3nzmupbYu3RZxNd2hIR5116Mm9y/C8TnK7F6KC6BVBLLJ1BfonMuumFTcCu9hke2U29a/XqhOpRFM2EGde6wWaPgDV2zjfQLSLjO1Tkj7jTe35vIeg5WZhdi91qHOvDSPcH3WcvbslNMHycLnPMANq0MsSO503VW7EsJNPRB8uEkBxAoCOPKG4URojk5+IBeKHHrKREKEJXDss+kiLNgi2flsjVjPpXk8fsMBOgJnSJ1Qjqpu/cAUw8fyn2byxMh7x4wxsBu+pbHm8lNprbmmxRwT4wtiSuQnEDtadeH7ocVJWPWKlEFsaR/w==</ds:SignatureValue><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIC1jCCAb6gAwIBAgIQPvWwoUDezpBMDadtU7hS5jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAnMSUwIwYDVQQDExxBREZTIFNpZ25pbmcgLSBzdHMuaGVydHoubmV0MB4XDTE3MDYxMjE1MDUyNVoXDTE5MDYxMjE1MDUyNVowJzElMCMGA1UEAxMcQURGUyBTaWduaW5nIC0gc3RzLmhlcnR6Lm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJXb56TyUfhianHvhHFFK4C5cETsH15fG2+s9rSUrRDIEpHIECMR6PRayzed/Yi8J7wgFkzMgnYUUGB4F0p8/TC8ruvY+CwXGP/BEEvE2N6WuZF9bWNuT304XvVZleZpfoB+RMhwzel+gHN5zaCNvlikEEgCsGoGtsVDidGBF57KgmJQcICIEf1u6VD6QrCAyahxrEKoAJU7t3VpSwYNLlqKGCYCo+dn09rk7RZFuHKdBFQQ8NjQZCUzhK9c64crv6ms8polQUNPldeapEsF1SFBPOfElG+N/17sg4UQ2BVbxFAFoH2eES2OFFn6oWEAi81oh+2iVuIVwDwhZE8cXIUCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAOb3GC2O2SPntVbZU7HoxgEcgWw7TDFXRxegE5GdnsyXIVEdSSzPH2g+Tc+Uaz5DZqEe/XtzGqAxItAe3f/94lZyL4WPkDaWtns44cEpO9q0Pf/GFbZeNHSeXgz1r9KIgTuETZ76eSCeHF4RZ2ZOQOxe4f2kY1l6ugRJqSKTEjqTXfZCvt/PVlW1LZegcMTuStCzQZ3rL/4lYqUa/ez7H8yEsLOVXTgWMxiEhk0VPomXJSWtrLjFsVBqB6QCh1RGGlR0uO3Sn6HAINiWravjM8XOaLAn/cM9L7m8XDVH6+oEutH1sST9fb/OwwJFEj4sU8jwQN0Z+KX7lC6fq121bGw==</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></KeyInfo></ds:Signature><Subject><NameID>NH37782</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_6b17407f6451fc54076e" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-06T14:21:27.985Z" Recipient="httrtz.com" /></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Conditions NotBefore="2018-12-06T14:16:27.983Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-12-06T15:16:27.983Z"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>.com</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group"><AttributeValue>RETURN_THIS_VALUE</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-12-06T14:16:27.881Z" SessionIndex="_e90c2462-47e1-4e13-ac87-10e7d0aca2ff"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion></samlp:Response>';

var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");

var doc = oDOM.querySelector('AttributeValue').textContent;

console.log(doc);
```

Comment: It works on here but in the browser that doc variable always comes back undefined. Any ideas why?

Comment: @user68288, all StackOverflow snippets run **in browser**. I think something is wrong with your `text` variable. How are you getting it?

Comment: Using the following code.


`const body = req.body.SAMLResponse;


var b = new Buffer(body, 'base64');


let text = b.toString('ascii');


console.log('formmatted saml', text);`    @Kosh Very

Comment: @user68288, `req` and `Buffer` are not defined for me. So what is logged for `text` in the console?

Comment: I added a sample of what text would like -- had to hide some of the values but I am sure you realize that.

Comment: @user68288, your sample was parsed correctly as well.

Comment: So any ideas at all why it is coming back as undefined? Any other methods for producing this?

Comment: actually when I do your exact code I get the following error:

`TypeError: oDOM.querySelector is not a function` @Kosh Very   -- do I need to install query-selector for npm?